# How to display custom 404 page when rewrite <action url=".."> points to missing file?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, custom-error-pages

The site I'm working on (.Net 4.0 & VS2010 on IIS8) uses a single  rule to rewrite *all* incoming URLs to .aspx pages existing in a single "/pages/" folder. For example, "www.site.com/hello" is rewritten to "/pages/hello.aspx".

The current rewrite rule is this:

```
    <rule name="pages" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([a-z0-9_-]+(?:/[a-z0-9_-]+)*)/?$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/pages/{R:1}.aspx" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

This is working fine, but I'm struggling to implement a custom 404 redirection for when either of the following are true:

a) The url format defined in the  regex is not matched (i.e. the strict url format was not adhered to), or

b) The url regex is matched, but the rewrite to `url="/pages/{R:1}.aspx"` does not exist (e.g. the url is "/pages" but the physical file "/pages/hello.aspx" does not exist).

Can that be accomplished with rewite rules?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the purpose of `stopProcessing="false"`. :)

The rewritten url can be further tested in the next rule, to redirect to a 404 page if it does not end up pointing to an existing file. The working code is:

```
<rule name="pages" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^([a-z0-9_-]+(?:/[a-z0-9_-]+)*)/?$"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/pages/{R:1}.aspx" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="404" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="pages/Error404.aspx" />
</rule>
```